# What does __bases__ in __init__(self) mean?

Tags: python

In a certain [library](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/09babc70ab20b0c28a1626987aa176c34250a57e/jira/resources.py#L1472) I found the following construction:

```
class PropertyHolder:
    def __init__(self, raw):
        __bases__ = raw  # noqa
```

What can this be used for?

Comment: That makes no sense at all.  `__bases__` is just a local variable here, which vanishes as soon as the `.__init__()` method ends.

Comment: Looks like the [`else`](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/09babc70ab20b0c28a1626987aa176c34250a57e/jira/resources.py#L1467) right above it does nothing at all either.

Comment: @Bharel It's *equivalent* to putting the last `return` statement right after the `for` loop; I wouldn't say it's doing *nothing*. (In any case, it has nothing to do with the question.)

Answer (score 2):

It does absolutely nothing, probably a bug in the code. Just sets a random local variable which immediately gets deleted.

Looks like it was added in [issue #306](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/306#issuecomment-339168653) as an attempt to fix pickling  a dynamic class. Needless to say, the pickling works because this code does nothing. They even ignored the linter (`# noqa`) when it told them it does nothing.

I've opened an [appropriate issue](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/1332).

Update:

Issue was fixed and code was removed